# Why doesn't jQuery.css method change anything?

Tags: jquery

In debug I typed the following selector:

```
$('.jspPane')
```

Result:

[image]

Then I tried to change the div:

```
$('.jspPane').css({"padding":"1px; top: 1px;"});
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see nothing changed.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: typo: `1px; top: 1px;` is not valid for `padding`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see there is the *style* attribute that contains `"padding: 0px; top: -737px;"`.

In this case you want to change *padding* and *top*.

```
$('.jspPane').css({ padding: 1, top: 1 }); // or { padding: "1px", top: "1px" }
```

In the `.css()` method you need to write the *CSS property* you want to change, and not the direct string from style.

---

The method allows more ways to pass the property names.

One of the ways does not accept chaining properties in the same method. Instead you need to chain the methods

```
$(selector).css('propertyName', 'string or integer to write in property')
           .css('propertyName', 'string or integer to write in property');
```

On the other hand by passing an object you'll be able to chain properties

```
$(selector).css({
  propertyName: 'string or integer to write in property',
  propertyName2: 'string or integer to write in property'
});
```

---

Alternatively you could just edit the style attribute

```
$('.jspPane').attr('style', "padding: 1px; top: 1px;");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this incorrectly.The correct syntax is (to apply padding from the top)

```
$('.jspPane').css("padding","1px 0 0 0");
```

[Example to change css](http://jsfiddle.net/on4xesdq/1/)